# How to spin up a ETCD docker container and restore a backup obtained from a kubernetes ETCD Cluster node?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kubernetes, etcd

I am trying to spin up a ETCD node in docker and restore a backup obtained from the Kubernetes Cluster node.

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379  --user=root:'root' snapshot save snapshot.db
```

I have obtained the snapshot and have it downloaded locally. How could i restore onto a already spinned up etcd node?

The following command was used to spin up the container.I have mounted a data volume.

```
docker run -d --restart always \
  -p 2379:2379 \
  -p 2380:2380 \
  --volume=etcd-volume:/etcd-data \
  --name etcd gcr.io/etcd-development/etcd:latest \
  /usr/local/bin/etcd \
  --data-dir=/etcd-data --name etcd \
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://127.0.0.1:2380 --listen-peer-urls 
  http://0.0.0.0:2380 \
  --advertise-client-urls http://127.0.0.1:2379 --listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379 \
  --initial-cluster etcd=http://127.0.0.1:2380
```

Then I tried to restore it using the following.

```
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl snapshot restore snapshot.db \
  --name m1 \
  --initial-cluster m1=http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster \
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --data-dir /var/lib/docker/volumes/etcd-volume
```

Both the ETCD cluster and docker are on two different VMs. I tried to execute the above command from the local machine as etcdctl tool has to be installed in docker to execute that command. The restoration has not happened. I just need the keys to be copied onto the new. Any suggestion on how I could do it?

Comment: Is there an error? What does the snapshot restore tells you?

Comment: I have done a small library implementation to copy and insert ETCD keys from one node to another in golang. https://github.com/anjulapaulus/etcd-replicator